JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri from cloud config
I have configured my application to log as JSON using log4j2 configuration:
Configuration:

  status: warn

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: CONSOLE
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      JsonTemplateLayout:
        eventTemplateUri: "classpath:log4j2/templates/jsonLayout.json"

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: INFO
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: CONSOLE

at the moment is using a file in the classpath (as configured on property JsonTemplateLayout.eventTemplateUri), but since I have a cloud config server, I would like to move that file into the cloud config server to be centralized and used by all microservices.
how can I do that?
GitHub discussion: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/discussions/2536
GitHub issue: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/2537
